# how to tell if a heat equation has steady state

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$u_{t}=u_{xx}+f(x,t)  \\ u(0,t)=A(t) \\ u(1 , t)=B(t) \\ u(x,0)=g(x)$$
Under what condition does steady state solution exist? If exists, is it a must to solve this equation by first substituting steady state solution? For example, if f independent of t and A,B=positive constants then steady state solution exist...

Comment: A steady state solution is a solution that the system will approach as $t \rightarrow \infty$. To exist it requires both boundary conditions to approach a constant value as $t \rightarrow \infty$, and also for $f(x,t)$ to approach a constant distribution as $t \rightarrow \infty $.

Comment: I doubt that a non-zero steady state exists. For vanishing $f$ there is no such state. For constant $f$ there appears a term $ft$ that grows linearly in time.

Answer (score 0):

A steady state solution is a solution which is independent of time, i.e. $u(x,t) = u_0(x)$. Substituting this in the PDE, we see that
\begin{equation}
 0 = (u_0)_{xx} + f(x,t) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
must be true *for all $x$ and $t$ in the domain*. Taking the partial derivative to $t$ in $(1)$ then gives you a necessary condition that $f$ must satisfy.

Moreover, since $u_0(x)$ is independent of time, it must in particular be equal to the initial value $g(x)$. Using this observation in combination with $(1)$ will get you another condition for $f$.

I'm sure you can now work out the conditions for $A$ and $B$ yourself.

Comment: But maybe you are interested in the case that $f$ is an oscillating function of time, say a function of $x$ times $exp[iωt]$. Then, assuming that $u(x,t)$ is oscillating at the same frequency a non-zero result emerges. But one has to show that $u(x,t)$ approaches this expression for large times. This can probably be handled by Fourier transforming wrt the coordinate and Laplace transforming wrt time. A quick glance shows that a specific behaviour of $g(x)$ and $f(x,t)$ is required.

Comment: Certainly, but this extends beyond what I would regard as a 'steady state'.